# Replace buggy function

Tags: python

I have a module A which imports buggy function like this:

```
from .B import buggy_fn as _buggy_fn
```

Is it possible to replace it outside?

```
import A
#...? = bug_free_implementation
```

Comment: Hey, to the anonymous close voters, since we are dealing with a newbie perhaps you expand them the courtesy of explaining what motivates your close votes, no? 

Answer (score 2):

```
import A
def bug_free_implementation():
    ...  
A._buggy_fn = bug_free_implementation
```

See also [monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching). Or `mock` even though that’s not its purpose.  But in any case you have to make sure your mod hits `A` before other stuff calls, or imports, `A`s original incorrect code.  You could also patch `B.buggy_fn` instead which would be even better.